# How to remove the border of a QComboBox down-arrow in PySide2 of PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyside2

I set a dark style background of the QComboBox, and the QComboBox show a border at the down-arrow,

```
self.storeComboBox.setStyleSheet("QComboBox { background: #262739; border-radius: 5px;}" }
```

[image: imgur link]

```
QComboBox::drop-down 
{
    border: 0px; /* also tried border:none */
}
```

I tried many way, but it didn't work, I don't know why?

Comment: what is your OS? what is the output of `print(app.style().objectName())`?

Comment: Is print macintosh, I use MacOS, I also change the style to "Fusion", still has the problem

Comment: try with: `self.storeComboBox.setStyleSheet("""

     QComboBox{ 
      background: #262739; 
      border-radius: 5px;
     }
     QComboBox::drop-down{
      border-left-color: #262739;
     }
     """)`

Comment: It can't work, still has the border

Comment: It seems to be a Qt bug for MacOS, in Linux it works correctly, report it.

Comment: By the way, I use PySide2, are you from Qt team?

Comment: If the problem is repeated in PySide2 and PyQt5 then the problem is not theirs but of Qt. No, I'm not from the Qt team.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, but removes the arrow icon and looks like the button disappears so you can set the background color to confirm it's still there.

```
QComboBox::drop-down:button{border-radius:5px; background:rgb(0,0,0)}
```

You can set a custom button icon with this,

```
QComboBox::down-arrow{image: url(./down.png)}
```

Comment: Which system do you use ?  this is a bug , i have reported it already.